# Not getting numbers and next line in Text View, while setting HTML content in TextView

Tags: android, html, textview

This is the code where I am setting the HTML content into the TextView.The HTML content is directly coming from the server.

```
Pair p = dataToBeShown.get(position);
    Log.e("syllabus",p.second.toString());
    MaterialDialog dialog =new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
            .title(p.first.toString())
            .content(Html.fromHtml(p.second.toString()))
            .show();
```

Getting output like: 
[image: Output of the code]

Expected Result:
Should be something like this

[image: Expected result]

What could possibly be wrong while setting content of the HTML?
Thanks, in advance!

Comment: did you tried bullet tag in html file??

Comment: That HTML content is coming from the server directly!

Comment: then make custom dialog...and  put webview in layout

Comment: Webview is heavier than the Textview, So I guess It wouldn't be fine and I want to rectify this error.